# Mysql - Select at least one or select none

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table as so...

```
----------------------------------------
| id |     name      |  group | number |
----------------------------------------
|  1 |          joey |      1 |     2  |
|  2 |         keidy |      1 |     3  |
|  3 |         james |      2 |     2  |
|  4 |        steven |      2 |     5  |
|  5 |         jason |      3 |     2  |
|  6 |         shane |      3 |     3  |
----------------------------------------
```

I'm running a select like so:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE number IN (2,3);
```

The problem im trying to solve is that I want to only grab get results from groups that have  1 or more rows of each number. For instance the above query is returning id's 1-2-3-5-6, when I'd like the results to exclude id 3 since the group of '2' can only return 1 result for the number of '2' and not for BOTH 2 and 3, since there's no row with the number 3 for the group 2 i'd like it to not even select id 3 at all.

Any help would be great.

Comment: your question is very confusing. Can you edit in a list of requirements/restrictions you want for the query instead of paragraph you have there?

Comment: What you want is called relational division. [This article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/ "Divided We Stand: The SQL of Relational Division") was posted in the section about Transact-SQL programming but at least some of the methods are coded in SQL that should be compilable in MySQL as well and at least some of the others should be implementable in MySQL without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1 t
 WHERE number IN(2, 3)
   AND EXISTS
(
  SELECT *
    FROM table1
   WHERE number IN(2, 3)
     AND `group` = t.`group`
   GROUP BY `group`
  HAVING MAX(number = 2) > 0
     AND MAX(number = 3) > 0
)
```

or

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1 t JOIN 
(
  SELECT `group`
    FROM table1
   WHERE number IN(2, 3)
   GROUP BY `group`
  HAVING MAX(number = 2) > 0
     AND MAX(number = 3) > 0
) q 
    ON t.`group` = q.`group`;
```

or

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1 
 WHERE `group` IN
(
  SELECT `group`
    FROM table1
   WHERE number IN(2, 3)
   GROUP BY `group`
  HAVING MAX(number = 2) > 0
     AND MAX(number = 3) > 0
);
```

Sample output (for both queries):

```
| ID |  NAME | GROUP | NUMBER |
|----|-------|-------|--------|
|  1 |  joey |     1 |      2 |
|  2 | keidy |     1 |      3 |
|  5 | jason |     3 |      2 |
|  6 | shane |     3 |      3 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0c0f6/5)** demo

Comment: I've never heard of SQLFiddle. That's awesome!

Answer (score 1):

On this, you can approach from a fun way with multiple joins for what you WANT qualified, OR, apply a prequery to get all qualified groups as others have suggested, but readability is a bit off for me..

Anyhow, here's an approach going through the table once, but with joins

```
select DISTINCT
      T.id,
      T.Name,
      T.Group,
      T.Number
   from
      YourTable T
         Join YourTable T2
            on T.Group = T2.Group AND T2.Group = 2
         Join YourTable T3
            on T.Group = T3.Group AND T3.Group = 3
   where
      T.Number IN ( 2, 3 )
```

So on the first record, it is pointing to by it's own group to the T2 group AND the T2 group is specifically a 2... Then again, but testing the group for the T3 instance and T3's group is a 3.

If it cant complete the join to either of the T2 or T3 instances, the record is done for consideration, and since indexes work great for joins like this, make sure you have one index for your NUMBER criteria, and another index on the (GROUP, NUMBER) for those comparisons and the next query sample...

If doing by more than this simple 2, but larger group, prequery qualified groups, then join to that

```
select
      YT2.*
   from
      ( select YT1.group
           from YourTable YT1
           where YT1.Number in (2, 3)
           group by YT1.group
           having count( DISTINCT YT1.group ) = 2 ) PreQualified
      JOIN YourTable YT2
         on PreQualified.group = YT2.group
         AND YT2.Number in (2,3)
```

Comment: This method is the only one of all responses that works the way I need it. Thank you.

Comment: @JoeyCadle, glad it worked for you... and FYI, you should start up-checking answers that are good, and CHECKMARK the answers that are the SOLUTION.  Otherwise, people won't know if it is resolved or not and waste their time trying to offer a solution when you may never look back at it again.

Comment: I upvoted this on Dec 6 22:54, maybe you just needed to reload the page? dunno.

Comment: @JoeyCadle, I appreciate the upvote.  In addition, so others know the question is resolved, there is also a checkmark to the left of questions indicating "THIS SOLVED IT"... Also in case anyone else searching and has similar issue knows which one actually worked too.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this,if I understand you

```
  SELECT id FROM table WHERE `group` IN
    (SELECT `group` FROM table WHERE number IN (2,3) 
    GROUP BY `group` 
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT number)=2)
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/181fd/6)

This will return all ids where BOTH numbers exist in a group.Remove DISTINCT if you want ids for groups where just one numbers is in.

Comment: This would only return 1 id per group, where I believe he needs all the ids. I would think to use a sub query with your current query.